# Can one filter/search SVN subversion.tigris.org/issues to differentiate open vs closed tickets?

Tags: svn

OK, either this is so dumb or maybe the open source tool needs some help from tool maker people. When I have problems with Subversion, I would like to search their tickets repository, http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/ . However, even with advanced search I cannot subset or sort on whether the issues are already closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Issue tracking query](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/query.cgi) web page, it appears that one of the criteria I can set for a query is Resolution.

[Apache](http://subversion.apache.org/) took over the support and maintenance of Subversion back in November 2009.  Here's the [Apache Subversion Issues](http://subversion.apache.org/reporting-issues.html) web page.

Comment: thank you so much Gilbert! For the record, here is the un-advanced search URL, which has much less info than the query.cgi page; http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/Search?mode=advanced .